# Java, send multiple get request per second

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

How to send N (N > 100) request per second to specify URL in java? 
I'm using ExecutorService and CountDownLatch for it.

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(DEFAULT_LATCH_COUNT);
    for (int i = 0; i < requestNumber; i++) {
        executor.submit(RequestFactory.getInstance().createRequester(latch, url));
    }
    latch.countDown();
```

But creating new Thread for each request is not good practice, isn't it ?
If I must send 500 asynchronous request per second I must create 500 threads.
Is this a right way to solve it or are there other solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

Having 500 threads would be bad practice, because it will incur unnecessary overhead for context switching between threads, not to mention the initialization overhead of creating 500 threads.

Keep in mind that the amount of threads that can run in parallel is limited by the number of available processors (i.e. `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`).  So if your computer has 8 available processors, there is no point in making more than 8 worker threads.

As for actually performing the work, this is a cookie cutter worker queue scenario.  Here you can create the number of worker threads equal to the number of available processors, and have each worker thread perform chunks of work until all of the work is completed (tracked by an `AtomicInteger` or something similar)